# Unable to connect to AWS RDS SQL Server database in MVC application

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services

I have a small ASP.NET MVC project that I want to connect to an AWS RDS SQL Server instance.

When I try to connect to it (via a test) I get:

> Cannot open database "database" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'user'.

**I am** able to connect to the instance (via [SSMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio) and in VS2013 Server Explorer) and really don't know what to do next

The connection string is defined in `Web.config` like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add 
    name="SystemDbContext"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=someInstance.rds.amazonaws.com,1433;
    Initial Catalog=babychange;User ID=user;Password=somePassword" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I have checked the **DataSource**,**User ID** and **Password** several times and am *sure* they are correct.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Did you tried to connect with same database with Management Studio ?

Comment: Read the penultimate line in my post - I am able to connect to the instance

Comment: I don't know why you are using UDL to connect. Please try simply with SSMS.

Comment: Does that user have rights?  Try to connect via SSMS to that server as that user with that password.

Comment: @NRKirby And you don't tell us whether you're able to connect via SSMS. That part is important.

Comment: I do not have SSMS installed tho I am able to connect via Server Exporer in VS2013

Comment: I now have SSMS installed - I can connect to the database with the same credentials that are failing in my project?

Comment: Check the errorLog. The errorlog will contain an login error code which will tell you what's exactly wrong (wrong password for example). I had this one time myself... and at the end... I was embarressed :)